# Display Product Reviews in product details page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, review

Somehow I am not getting Review comments in the Product Detail page in magento2.

My code from this file:

`app/design/frontend/Magento/mytheme/Magento_Review/templates/helper/summary.phtml`

is as follows:

```
<?php $url = $block->getReviewsUrl() . '#reviews'; ?>
<?php $urlForm = $block->getReviewsUrl() . '#review-form'; ?>
<?php if ($block->getReviewsCount()): ?>
<?php $rating = $block->getRatingSummary(); ?>
```

Comment: My Custom code resides here /app/design/frontend/Magento/themeaircare/Magento_Catalog/templates/custom/review.html   

$objectManagerr = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $registry = $objectManagerr->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
 $product = $registry->registry('current_product');
$blockList = $objectManagerr->get('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');  
                         
$templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
$reviewsummary = $blockList->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, $templateType,true);